# VS 2019 Android Emulator went missing

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Due to some circumstances, I needed to uninstall and install my computer's java. But after reinstalling and restarting my machine, I now get this problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create an android application using Xamarin. However I cant find my android devices to run my apps.

[image]

If I click the 'Android Emulator', It opens the Android Device Manager and asks me to create a default android device every time (Even if I created one, it keeps asking).

[image]

How am I gonna show my android devices so I could run my app?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to show the previously created virtual machine or physical machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please Install Google - api supported emulators